# What causes the interactive grid's "move" notification to fire?

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-18.2

I am using Apex 18.2. The "move" notification in the JSDoc is said to be Sent when one or more records are moved. But I can not find a way to move records. When does it fire and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move records using the model's `moveRecords` method: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/18.2/aexjs/model.html#moveRecords

Here's an example that would move the employees JONES and SCOTT in the EMP table after ALLEN...
Before:
[image]

This code would move the rows:

```
var model = apex.region('emp-reg').widget().interactiveGrid("getCurrentView").model;
var recordsToMove = [];
var recordToMoveAfter;

recordsToMove.push(model.getRecord('7566'));
recordsToMove.push(model.getRecord('7788'));

recordToMoveAfter = model.getRecord('7499');

model.moveRecords(recordsToMove, null, recordToMoveAfter);
```

After:

[image]

Comment: So, it's only for us as developers not for the user? There is no way the user can drag and drop a row or more and move them after or before another row, right?

Comment: I am unaware of a drag and drop feature for end-users at the moment.